# Device connect/disconnect notification via Bluez DBus API

Tags: dbus, bluez

How can I receive a signal or notification when a connection is created or destroyed through bluez dbus API?

Polling `Connected()` of all devices under /org/bluez/hci0 works but it is not an efficient way, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen on `PropertiesChanged` signal on the `org.bluez.Device1` interface. I don't have direct example for the device interface, but the template is below,

```
static void bluez_signal_device_changed(GDBusConnection *conn,
                    const gchar *sender,
                    const gchar *path,
                    const gchar *interface,
                    const gchar *signal,
                    GVariant *params,
                    void *userdata)
{
    (void)conn;
    (void)sender;
    (void)path;
    (void)interface;
    (void)userdata;

    GVariantIter *properties = NULL;
    GVariantIter *unknown = NULL;
    const char *iface;
    const char *key;
    GVariant *value = NULL;
    const gchar *signature = g_variant_get_type_string(params);

    if(strcmp(signature, "(sa{sv}as)") != 0) {
        g_print("Invalid signature for %s: %s != %s", signal, signature, "(sa{sv}as)");
        goto done;
    }

    g_variant_get(params, "(&sa{sv}as)", &iface, &properties, &unknown);
    while(g_variant_iter_next(properties, "{&sv}", &key, &value)) {
        if(!g_strcmp0(key, "Connected")) {
            if(!g_variant_is_of_type(value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)) {
                g_print("Invalid argument type for %s: %s != %s", key,
                        g_variant_get_type_string(value), "b");
                goto done;
            }
            g_print("Device is \"%s\"\n", g_variant_get_boolean(value) ? "Connected" : "Disconnected");
        }
    }
done:
    if(properties != NULL)
        g_variant_iter_free(properties);
    if(value != NULL)
        g_variant_unref(value);
}


GDBusConnection *con = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, NULL, NULL);
prop_changed = g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(con,
                    "org.bluez",
                    "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                    "PropertiesChanged",
                    NULL,
                    "org.bluez.Device1",
                    G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE,
                    bluez_signal_device_changed,
                    NULL,
                    NULL);
```

With the above sample code, signal handling function `bluez_signal_device_changed` is called whenever a property is change in the Device` interface.

You can find more examples in https://gist.github.com/parthitce and explanation in https://www.linumiz.com/

Comment: Thanks. I listened to the `PropertiesChanged` signal on `/org/bluez`. When a phone connected to my device, I got two signals. One includes `UUIDs` and `ServiceResolved` (true). The other includes `Name` and `Alias`. When disconnected, I got another two signals. One includes `UUIDs`, where one UUID is lost but two other ones remain, and the other includes `ServiceResovled` (false) and `Connected` (false). So, `Connected` doesn't change in-pair. Donno why bluez developers adopted such a design. Now I try to rely on `ServiceResolved`. Hope it works.

Comment: @matianfu `Connected` is meant for connection status of the device as mentioned here https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt#n174. So when the device is connected after after service resolving, then this status changes. When you disconnect, then it toggles back.